# Showing that the sequence $a_{n+3}=5a^6_{n+2}+3a^3_{n+1}+a^2_n$, with $a_1=2019$, $a_2=2020$, $a_3=2021$, contains no numbers of the form $m^6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, contest-math

Here's a problem that I couldn't solve in a recent olympiad in which I took part. The problem says

> The sequence of real numbers $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3,\cdots$  is defined as follows: $a_1 = 2019,$ $a_2 = 2020,$ $a_3 = 2021$ and for any $ n \ge 1$ holds that:
> $$ a_{n+3} = 5a^{6}_{n+2} + 3a^{3}_{n+1} + a^{2}_{n} $$ Prove that this sequence does not contain numbers of the form $m^{6}$ for $m \in \mathbb{N}.$

This was the only problem I didn't even could make process, I asked some peers about it but they gave me ideas of calculus and I didn't undertand very well. I would like to get some ideas of how to solve it I don't really want a solution, instead I wanna try to solve it by myself.

**Edit 1. Proving important lemma of the problem and general fact (See @TonyK comment).**
For proving that we'll consider the following. As it is well-know there exists 7 clases $ \equiv$ (mod 7) {0,1,2,3,4,5,6}. So a single number can only belongs to one of the 7 clases. Let $m$ be our number and $m \in \mathbb{Z} $, is clear that if $m$ belongs to the $0$ class, $m^6 \equiv 0$ (mod 7).
Now supose that $m \equiv 1\pmod 7$. Then:
\begin{align}
  m^2 &\equiv 1\pmod{7}\\  m^3 &\equiv 1\pmod{7}\\ &\; \;  \vdots \notag \\ m^6 &\equiv 1\pmod{7} 
\end{align}
Supose that $ m \equiv 2\pmod{7}$. Then:
\begin{align}
  m^2 &\equiv 4\pmod{7}\\
  m^3 &\equiv 8 \equiv 1\pmod{7} \\
 m^4 & \equiv 2 \pmod{7}\\
 m^5 & \equiv 4\pmod{7}\\ 
m^6 &\equiv 8 \equiv 1\pmod{7} 
\end{align}
Now you can consider from $3$ up to $6\bmod 7$ the same way we just did with $m \equiv 2\pmod{7}$, for explain this consider the numbers $n_i$ such that $n_i \equiv i\pmod{7}$ and if you follow the same way as in $m \equiv 2\pmod{7}$ you'll get:
\begin{align}
  n^{6}_1 &\equiv 1\pmod{7}\\
  n^{6}_2 &\equiv 1\pmod{7}\\ &\; \;  \vdots \notag \\
 n^{6}_6 &\equiv 1\pmod{7} \blacksquare
\end{align}
Which means that $\forall m \in \mathbb{N} $ when $ m \ne  7k $ for $ k \in \mathbb{Z}$, holds that  $ m^6 \equiv 1\pmod{7}$.

**Second ultra easier proof.** By FLTh $a^{7-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$ $\blacksquare$

Comment: Which Olympiad is this from?

Comment: ORO 2021 (Northern Regional Mexican Olympiad).

Comment: Do you have a link to the website, can't seem to find it.

Comment: No actually there isn't website since it is an exclusive contest for only some states (the north side of the country).

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thank you Jonh. You were right and your assertions were on point. I just fixed the mistake (:

Comment: `\pmod{7}` is the correct way to type it.

Comment: @oscarAMVS Another easy way to prove FLT for a general $p$ prime is as follows. Obviously, $a\equiv 0\bmod p\implies a^{p-1}\equiv 0\bmod p$. Consider $a\not\equiv 0\bmod p$. Then, the map $f:\mathbb Z_p\setminus \{0\}\to \mathbb Z_p\setminus\{0\}, x\mapsto ax$ is injective, as $\bmod p$: $ax\equiv ay\iff a(x-y)\equiv 0$, but then $p\mid a(x-y)\implies p\mid x-y\implies x\equiv y\bmod p$ do to Euclid's Lemma. Thus $f$ is injective, and since $\lvert{\mathbb Z_p\setminus \{0\}}\rvert=p-1$ is finite, $f$ is bijective.

Comment: Hence, $\bmod p: \{1,2,\ldots, p-1\}\equiv\{a, 2a, \ldots, (p-1)a\}$, so \begin{align*}\bmod p:\quad  & 1\cdot 2\cdots (p-1)\equiv a\cdot 2a\cdots (p-1)a=1\cdot 2\cdots (p-1)\cdot a^{p-1}\\&\iff  1\equiv a^{p-1} \end{align*}

Comment: Very good, beautiful I'd say

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Compute a few values modulo $7$. You will see a pattern. Can any of these values be a sixth power modulo $7$?

**Updated to add:** My initial values were out, so I thought this problem was easier than it is. You actually have to go as fas as $a_{15}$ to see the repeating pattern $\;4,3,3,4,\;\;4,3,3,4,\ldots$

But if $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ are both equal to $3$ or $4\bmod 7$, then so is $a_{n+3}$. So you only need to go as far as $a_7\equiv 3, a_8\equiv 4, a_9\equiv 3\bmod 7$ to show that $a_n$ is never equal to $0$ or $1$ $\bmod 7$ (and hence that $a_n$ is never a sixth power).

Comment: I've been practicing this and I've found a bounch of quite interesting stuff. First of all I discovered that, for all $m \in \mathbb{N} $ holds that $m^6 \equiv 1 (mod 7)$. And also prove in the following way.

Comment: @oscarAMVS: that is not quite right: if $m$ is divisible by $7$, then $m^6\equiv 0\bmod 7$. See [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) for more.

Comment: You're right I forgot to put that, I was writting the proof.

Comment: Now @TonyK, the idea key you gave and then I formally discover is to use the congruence modulo 7 to prove that the sequence would never have remainder 0 or 1 afert division by 7. I was experimenting with the sequence mod 7. I found the following stuff.

Comment: \begin{align}
  a_4 &\equiv 3\pmod{7}\\
  a_5 &\equiv  4\pmod{7} \\
 a_6 & \equiv -1\pmod{7}\\
 a_7 & \equiv 3\pmod{7}\\ 
a_8 &\equiv 4\pmod{7} \\ a_9 & \equiv 3\pmod{7} \\ a_{10} & \equiv 3\pmod{7} \\ a_{11} & \equiv 4\pmod{7}
\end{align}

Comment: @oscarAMVS, I don't think your figures are correct. They are not the same as mine, at any rate $-$ the first disagreement is at $a_6$.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same cos, I wasn't getting a pattern, I'm working on that :)

Comment: @oscarAMVS: Sorry, my mistake. Your figures are correct. This problem is not as easy as I thought!